# Write Text Vertically at 270deg using CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-text

I am working on an example where i want to write text vertically at 90 deg and 270deg.

Example at [JSFiddlle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9LGX/31/)

It seems to be working in FF but doesn't show up in IE at all.

I tried to change certain properties with no luck.

I would appreciate if someone can help me resolve this so that it works across all browsers.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way i have done along with Jquery is much better and help to get around the browser issue as i faced in other example

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/1865/

I think this is best suited for my example & works well in IE without any issue with font also. I am  write text in div and rotating it with jQuery plug in.

Has issues with IE 8 & below

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support this along with most other CSS3 functions.

Although you could try this guys solution:

http://scottgale.com/blog/css-vertical-text/2010/03/01/

Answer (score 1):

because its using webkit, moz and o css3 properties to rotate it. IE supports none of these css attributes

Comment: detect IE and have an alert pop up and tell users to upgrade to a modern browser that works ?, failing that check this out : http://www.aquim.com/web-article-226.html

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange but when I remove `Helvetica` from your CSS it all seems to work fine. Are you sure the text displays when you remove the rotation?

Also, the `height: -150px` might be causing a problem. Try using margins instead.

You might want to add

```
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
```

for modern IE.

[The demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SidewaysHeaders/) from this article works fine in IE9 for me:
[css-tricks.com/sideways-headers](http://css-tricks.com/sideways-headers/)

This one is good too: [css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/)